# UIButtonの形を変える

Tags: swift, xcode

UIButtonを扇型に変形させようとして、UIBezierPathを使い、扇型を描画しようとしましたが、どのように式を組み立てればいいのか分からず、質問させていただいております。
やり方がわかるという方がいましたら、教えていただければと思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

扇型というとこんな感じでいいでしょうか？

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 20))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(40, 0), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(0, 20), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(11, 0))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(80, 20), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(69, 0), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(80, 20))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(40, 56))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 20))
bezierPath.closePath()
UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
bezierPath.fill()
```

[image: 扇型]